# Scraping result is different from inspected DOM element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to parse list of price in a web page using Selenium webdriver in Python. So, I try to fetch all the DOM elements using this code

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/flights/explore/#explore;f=BDO;t=r-Asia-0x88d9b427c383bc81%253A0xb947211a2643e5ac;li=0;lx=2;d=2018-01-09'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

print(driver.page_source)
```

The problem is what I got from `page_source` is different from what I see in the inspected element

```
<div class="CTPFVNB-f-a">
    <div class="CTPFVNB-f-c"></div>
    <div class="CTPFVNB-f-d elt="toolbelt"></div>
    <div class="CTPFVNB-f-e" elt="result">Here is the difference</div>
</div>
```

The difference exist inside the `CTPFVNB-f-e` class. In the inspected DOM element, this tag hold all the prices that I want to fetch. But, in the result of `page_source`, this part is missing.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Or do I need further steps to parse the list of prices?

Comment: The content you're trying to retrieve is dynamically generated using JavaScript. It's not present in the page source.

Comment: may be you need to wait till the full DOM loading. add some delay and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is modifying the page after the page loads. As you are printing page source immediately after opening the page, you're getting the initial code without the execution of JavaScript.

You can do any one of the following things:

- **Add delay:** Using `time.sleep(x)` (change value of `x` according to your requirements. it is in seconds) (**NOT** recommended)
- **Implicit wait:** `driver.implicitly_wait(x)` (again `x` is same as above)
- **Explicit wait:** Wait for the HTML element to appear and then get the page source. To learn how to do this, [refer this link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). (**HIGHLY** recommended)

Using **explicit wait** is the **better option** here as it waits only for the time required for the element to become visible. Thus won't cause any excess delays. Or if the page loads slower than expected, you won't get the desired output using implicit wait.