# Not able to Scrape data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Selenium to login to the webpage and getting the webpage for scraping
I'm able to get the page.
I have searched the html for a table that I wanted to scrape.
here it is:-

```
<table cellspacing="0" class=" tablehasmenu table hoverable sensors" id="table_devicesensortable">
```

This is the script :-

```
rawpage=driver.page_source #storing the webpage in variable
souppage=BeautifulSoup(rawpage,'html.parser') #parsing the webpage
tbody=souppage.find('table', attrs={'id':'table_devicesensortable'}) #scrapping
```

I'm able to get the parsed webpage in souppage variable.
but not able to scrape and store in tbody variable.

Answer (score 3):

Required table might be generated dynamically, so you need to wait until its presence on page:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

tbody = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "table_devicesensortable")))
```

Also note that there is no need in using BeautifulSoup as Selenium has enough built-in methods and properties to do the same job for you, e.g.

```
headers = tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name("th")
rows = tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
cells = tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
cell_values = [cell.text for cell in cells]
etc...
```

Comment: Thanx for the info

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to scrape the `<table>` you have induce [*WebDriverWait*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) with `expected_conditions` clause set to [`presence_of_element_located`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) and to achieve that you can use either of the following code blocks :

- Using `class`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class=' tablehasmenu table hoverable sensors' and @id='table_devicesensortable']")))
  rawpage=driver.page_source #storing the webpage in variable
  souppage=BeautifulSoup(rawpage,"html.parser") #parsing the webpage
  tbody=souppage.find("table",{"class":" tablehasmenu table hoverable sensors"}) #scrapping
  ```
- Using `id`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class=' tablehasmenu table hoverable sensors' and @id='table_devicesensortable']")))
  rawpage=driver.page_source #storing the webpage in variable
  souppage=BeautifulSoup(rawpage,"html.parser") #parsing the webpage
  tbody=souppage.find("table",{"id":"table_devicesensortable"}) #scrapping
  ```

Comment: i had tried with both these method before posting but none of them is working.

Comment: Updated my answer with your requirement to wait for the dynamically fetched contents and successful data scraping. let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching on stackoverflow for the issue and came across this post

[BeautifulSoup returning none when element definitely exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100398/beautifulsoup-returning-none-when-element-definitely-exists)

By reading the answer provided by luiyezheng i got the hint that might be as the data is fetched dynamically.So, the table might got created dynamically and hence i was unable to find.

So, the work around is :-

before storing the webpage i put a delay

so the code goes like this

```
time.sleep(4)
rawpage=driver.page_source #storing the webpage in variable
souppage=BeautifulSoup(rawpage,"html.parser") #parsing the webpage
tbody=souppage.find("table",{"id":"table_devicesensortable"}) #scrapping
```

i hope it might help someone.

Comment: Using `time.sleep()` is against all best practices. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089338/7832176) will help you.